# GCP Cloud Function not correctly picking up/acknowledging PubSub messages

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I have some data processing workflows set up in Google Cloud Platform. These location process physical addresses and return some metrics about them. The workflows use combinations of Cloud Functions and PubSub streams.

With one Google Cloud Function in the workflow, some messages are not picked up from the triggering stream or are picked up multiple times. I know some level of this is expected. However, this is happening a lot. Enough that is causing 10x overstatements for some locations and no results for several others.

I think that the `callback` function is not acknowledging the messages correctly but I'm not sure what should be different to get more reliable pickup and acknowledgement of messages. Any suggestions are appreciated.

My GCP Cloud Function to retrieve metrics is triggered by a PubSub stream and executes the `retrieve_location` function sending data to a different PubSub stream. The `retrieve_location` function looks like this:

```
def retrieve_location(event, context):
    auth_flow()

    project_id = <my project id>
    subscription_name = <my subscription name>

    subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()

    subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(
        project_id, subscription_name)

    def callback(message):
        message.ack()
        message_obj = message.data
        message_dcde = message_obj.decode('utf-8')
        message_json = json.loads(message_dcde)

        get_metrics(message_json)


    subscriber.subscribe(subscription_path, callback=callback)
```

The `get_metrics` function takes the payload from each message, retrieves some data and sends it to another stream. This function seems to work as expected.

```
def get_metrics(loc):
    <... retrieve and process data, my_data is the object that gets sent to the next stream ...>
          project_id = <my project id>
          topic_name = <my topic name>
          topic_id = <my topic id>

          publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
          topic_path = publisher.topic_path(project_id, topic_name)

            try:
                publisher.publish(topic_path, data=my_data.encode('utf-8'))
            except Exception as exc:
                    print("topic publish failed: ", exc)
```

Comment: So is your Cloud Function triggered by a Pub/Sub message, causing it to start up a subscriber on a different Pub/Sub subscription? It is a little unusual to start up a Pub/Sub subscriber in this fashion.

Comment: @KamalAboul-Hosn The subscription and topic ids are all unique for each PubSub stream so there shouldn't be crossover. But what is the best way to start a subscriber?

Comment: I agree this is an unusual pattern. Can you explain at a high level why you need to do this?

Comment: @DustinIngram What is the best way to trigger a Function from a PubSub stream so all messages are picked up and processed? I am processing addresses and retrieving data for each one.

Comment: Just subscribing the function to the topic should be sufficient. It's still not clear to me why you need a second subscriber in the function?

Comment: @DustinIngram Please have another look. I don't think there is a second subscriber. I am subscribing to one topic in the `retrieve_location` function then publishing to another topic in the `get_metrics` function. If I am wrong, please post the specific line. And if there is a better way please add some specifics in an answer.

Comment: The line `subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()` defines a new subscriber.

Comment: @DustinIngram yes, and `SubscribeClient` is called once and its `subscribe` method is called once. Is there another line that also subscribes?

Comment: This is the second subscriber, the first subscriber is the `retrieve_location` background function itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting up a second Pub/Sub subscriber inside your Cloud Function, you should create a [background function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/background) that is subscribed to that topic which handles the payload directly, e.g.:

```py
def get_metrics_background_function(event, context):
    message_obj = event.data
    message_dcde = message_obj.decode('utf-8')
    message_json = json.loads(message_dcde)

    get_metrics(message_json)
```

Comment: I am working on making the changes you suggest. In this example there is no `message.ack()`. Is that not necessary?

Comment: It's not necessary, the successful execution of the Cloud Function has the effect of acknowledging the Pub/Sub message.

Comment: This was helpful. I had the specific subscriber declaration for local development of the Cloud Function logic. Removing the extra setup did help to reduce extra calls. However, what I have now are issues with calls that are not there but should be. At least this solved one problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might be conflating the use of Cloud Pub/Sub to trigger a Cloud Function with the use of Pub/Sub directly via the Cloud Pub/Sub client library. Generally, you would want to do one or the other.

If the subscription you created was done via Cloud Functions, then you `retrieve_location` function isn't really receiving and processing messages. Instead, what it is doing is starting up a subscriber client and shortly thereafter shutting down given the fact that `subscriber.subscribe` will just run to completion and therefore your function will complete execution.

If this function is starting up a client to the same subscription that triggers the Cloud Function, then it isn't actually going to do anything because Cloud-Function-based subscriptions use the [push](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push) model while the client library should be used with the [pull](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull) model.

You either want to perform the action in `callback` directly in `retrieve_location`, using the event as the message (as Dustin describes), or you'll want to set up a persistent subscriber with the client library, e.g., on GCE, that instantiates the subscriber and calls `subscribe` on it.

Comment: This detail was also quite helpful in figuring things out. Thanks for providing this insight!